# What does (n, n/2)^n mean?

Tags: symbolic

I am reading the wiki of [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming#A_type_of_balanced_0.E2.80.931_matrix) and can't understand the designation of [image]

What does that represent? thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is the nth power of the binomial n over n/2.